# php - if condition failing every time

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a simple php function.  however, it fails every time, no matter what.

```
function for determining tomato pic

echo "$info[2]";
function tomato()
{
    if(intval($info[2]) > 60)
        return "fresh";
    else if(intval($info[2]) < 60)
        return "rotten";
}
```

it echo 95 on the page but then returns "rotten". any idea whats up with this?

Comment: where do you define $info? Pass it to your function, or (dirty) use global: `function tomato(){ global $info; [...]`

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions do not inherit variables from the parent scope. There are a few ways around this:

1: Pass them as a parameter

```
function tomato($info) {...}
tomato($info);
```

2: If it is an anonymous function, use the `use` clause

```
$tomato = function() use ($info) {...}
```

3: (Not recommended) Use the `global` keyword to "import" the variable

```
function tomato() {
    global $info;
    ...
}
```

4: (Very bad idea, but added for completeness) Use the `$GLOBALS` array

```
function tomato() {
    // do stuff with $GLOBALS['info'][2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to make the variable known to the function, try

```
function tomato() {
    global $info;
    ...
```

alternatively, pass the value as argument to the function:

```
function tomato($tomatocondition) {
    if(intval($tomatocondition) > 60)
        return "fresh";
    else if(intval($tomatocondition) < 60)
        return "rotten";
```

and call it...

```
echo tomato($info[2]);
```

Comment: never use `global` pass the value as an argument instead.

Comment: declaring global crashes the page... passing as function works though, thank you!

Comment: @cryptic, Why? `Global` exists, but using of it cant be?

Comment: @cryptic, that's controversial =)